# What is the impact of CPU-Shares on Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, docker, containers, cgroups

My Question is more on the level of Java threads. But probably it might be more generic for OS level threads as well.

JAVA SPECIFIC: what would be the relevance of [ThreadPool Tuning Size](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html). (The formula)? The impact performance and how it behaves under the hood, with containers. (I think I can understand cpu-sets but not cpu-shares, I know what cpu-shares is just didn't understand how threading behaves here).

So I was an article reading about [java in containers](https://jaxenter.com/nobody-puts-java-container-139373.html),(which I have observed while running applications on CloudFoundary), [3](https://jaxenter.com/nobody-puts-java-container-139373.html) and the [enhancements](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146115) that were brought in JDK 10 for detecting container limits.

In the said article:

> Let’s take a short look at how the JVM adjust to the number of processors/cores available on the node it is running on. There are actually a number of parameters which by default are initialized based on core count.
>   So if the normal default values for GC-threads, JIT Threads etc are the total number of 'cores' available.

Now, If

> the number_of_cpus() will be calculated based on cpu_shares()/1024

Then in a scenario where let's say the CPU-Share is 512. This calculation would give 0. (I'm then assuming that the value would be rounded to 1?? ). 
How does this work then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be rounded to **1**.

The implementation is under `./hotspot/os/linux/osContainer_linux.cpp` and basically looks like this:

```
share_count = ceilf((float)share / (float)PER_CPU_SHARES);
```

where `PER_CPU_SHARES = 1024` and share is as per your example `512`. This function will result in `1`.

I am not very sure I understand you correctly with your edit, but a `cpu-share` matters when multiple containers running on the same OS try to use 100% of the CPU. Suppose you have 3 containers, one has `1024`, the other two have `512` cpu-shares. When *all* 3 of them try to get 100% of a CPU time, this is what will happen: 50% of the time will go to the container that has `1024` shares, the other ones will get each `25%`; but again this is only when the CPU is at `100%`.

And now read that JEP again - it only affects JIT/GC threads - not your application threads; you can still create a many threads as you could, so whatever that article suggests - it is still valid, container or no container.

Comment: Actually, I was interested in knowing multithreaded applications would behave under CPU-shares

Comment: I'm sorry no you did not. Ill elaborate the question.